# What's the react inline style for an anchor link?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set the standard properties of this anchor tag but I'm not sure of the syntax. How do I set the link color, visited color, hover, active etc}

```
const linkStyle = {
          ???
        }


linkFormatter = cell => <a style={linkStyle} href='' role="link" onClick={() => { this.clickToGoToList(cell); }} >{cell} </a>;
```

Comment: `const linkStyle = { color: 'limegreen' };` works fine to set the link color. You can't set visited/hover/active styles in an HTML element's `style` property, so you can't do it in React, either. For that you'll need to use a stylesheet or one of the many React style libraries.

Answer (score 1):

So the short answer is that you cannot access selectors/pseudo-selectors with inline style objects. Possible solutions:

1) Style them with css in a stylesheet (though this feels pretty hacky)

2) Use a styling library. [Glamorous](https://glamorous.rocks/) is my preference but [Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction) also has a React library. These libraries actually create React components to style elements and allow you access to pseudo-selectors like :active, :hover, and the like.

Comment: "you cannot access pseudo-selectors with inline style objects in React because they are part of the virtual DOM." This doesn't have anything to do with virtual DOM. The reason you can't use pseudoclass selectors in an inline in style React is that you can't use pseudoclass selectors (or any selectors) in a HTML element's `style` property.

Comment: You're right, this wording was very muddy. Answer updated.